# When $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\log(x)|^p dx <\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

For what values of $p \in \mathbb{R}$, does the integral
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\log(x)|^p dx
$$
converge? The logarithmic function grows very slowly, so I think only the integral around the origin matters.

Comment: The integral makes no sense: how do you compute the logarithm of a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 1):

The integral, as you wrote it, is meaningless. If you actually meant
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left| \log |x| \right|^p \, dx,
$$
then you just remark that the integrand is a radially symmetric function. As a consequence, and focusing only on a little ball $B=B(0,r)$ around the origin,
$$
\int_{B} \left| \log |x| \right|^p \, dx = |S^{n-1}| \int_0^r |\log t|^p t^{n-1}\, dt.
$$
The last is an improper integral of a single variable, and you it is much easier than you might imagine.